# How to show certain data on certain interval of period

Tags: custom-field, date-time

I have three sets of period of time, each with several interval of date:

Event A
Jan 1 - March 1
Dec 1 - Dec 31

Event B
Mar 2 - April 15
Jun 1 - Jul 15
Sept 1 - Oct 15

Event C
Apr 16 - May 31
Jul 16 - Aug 31
Oct 16 - Nov 30

I really would like to know how to show a custom field if today's date is fall between a certain period. Say today is April 22, then custom field to show is "Event C".

Really appreciate if someone can help me resolve this issue.

Comment: Not really sure what you're trying to achieve here, but I think you have to create your own custom sql query and you can have date comparison in mysql pretty easily => `date1 >= $myDate AND date2 <= $myDate`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a function you can put in functions.php.

```
function get_current_event() {
    global $post;
    $now = get_the_time('U');
    $year = get_the_time('Y');
    if($now >= strtotime("January 1 $year") && $now < strtotime("March 1 $year")) {
       return get_post_meta($post->ID,'eventA',true);
    }
    if($now >= strtotime("March 1 $year") && $now < strtotime("October 15 $year")) {
        return get_post_meta($post->ID,'eventB',true);
    }
    $nextyear = $year+1;
    if($now >= strtotime("October 15 $year") && $now < strtotime("January 1 $nextyear")) {
        return get_post_meta($post->ID,'eventC',true);
    }
    return false;
}
```

Then you can put this in your template:

```
print get_current_event();
```